# Overriding the distance metric in Clustering Algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I am trying to implement a K-means clustering algorithm across 3 dimensions.
Now the requirement is that I want the flexibility to define my own distance metric across any particular dimension. For ex, across dimension 1, I would want to define a simple euclidean distance measure, across dimensions 2 I want to define my own custom distance measure and so on.

Is there a JAVA implementation available for K-means clustering that lets me override the distance metric across any dimension of my choice?

Thanks
Abhishek S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/). It allows you to use arbitrary distance functions with most algorithms. Including k-means, although that is only partially sensible (k-means is actually *designed* for euclidean distance, and may stop converging with other distances, when the mean no longer minimizes distances!)

In fact, the ELKI people even have a [Tutorial on adding a custom distance function](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/DistanceFunctions) that pretty much answers your question, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/index.html) it has a simple K-means implementation and supports all kind of attributes (not only numeric ones), so I assume they hove some kind of API that lets you plugin your distance implementation.